# How to save post form in Laravel-4

Tags: laravel-4

I am creating parent email form in this form parent insert his email id.
I facing problem is when I submit form that showing error ,`Method [save] does not exist` 
and my code is

registration  form

```
<div class="form">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/api/v1/parents/registration_step_2', 'class' => "worldoo-form form form-horizontal", 'id' => "signupForm", 'method' => "post" )) }}
      <div class="form-group ">
        {{ Form::label('cemail', 'Please enter your parents e-mail:', array('class' => "control-label"));}}
        <div class="">
          {{ Form::email('cemail', '', array('class' => "form-control", 'id' => "cemail"));}}
          <i class="sprite success form-control-feedback"></i> </div>
        <h5 class="regular-font text-left">Your parents will need to activate your account before you can access worldoo.</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="text-center">
          {{Form::submit('Next', array('class' => "btn btn-primary"));}}
        </div>
      </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

my controller

```
public function registrationStepTwo()
{

    $cemail = $_REQUEST['cemail'];

    if($cemail != '')
    {
        $parent = new Parent;
        $parent->email = $cemail;
        $parent->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Laravel's Eloquent models. Did you declare your Parent model? Can your parent model code? Also, for Laravel-ish way, use `Input::get('cemail')` instead of `$_REQUEST`

Comment: not working given same error method[save] doesn't work

Comment: show us your model first.

Comment: <?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Parent extends Eloquent  implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
protected $guarded = array();public static $rules = array('email' => 'required','name' => 'required','username' => 'required','password' => 'required','mobile' => 'required','secret_question_id' => 'required','secret_answer' => 'required','city' => 'required');protected $hidden = array('password','remember_token');}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the save issues, with the exact same class name "Parent" at it also throws

> Method [save] does not exist

The reason you can save the `$parent` model data is because of the name that you have given to the model as

> Parent

Change the model name to something else and it will work as expected. Looks like the class Parent must be laravel's system class and we cannot give that name to our custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

your Model is not set up correctly you find these in app/models/ there needs to be a Parent.php file that defines how laravel should use your information in the database. [Eloquent Models - Laravel 4 Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Comment: In Parent.php model have five fields but I insert only one fields so this reason to show error...

Comment: 5 Fields? could you post your code on the model please

Comment: <?php use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait; use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface; use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait; use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface; class Parent extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface { use UserTrait, RemindableTrait; protected $guarded = array();public static $rules = array('email' => 'required','name' => 'required','username' => 'required','password' => 'required','mobile' => 'required','secret_question_id' => 'required','secret_answer' => 'required','city' => 'required');protected $hidden = array('password','remember_token');}

Answer (score 0):

I have tested, this code is working properly. May be try composer update.

```
composer update
```